# What is Limits.getInteractionQueries() used for?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits, documentation

Browsing the [`Limits` class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Limits_static_methods.htm) recently, I saw there was a `getInteractionQueries()` and `getLimitInteractionQueries()` method.

Can anyone tell me what this Limit refers to?
Running the `getLimitInteractionQueries()` call it gives me "1000".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Spring '14 Release Notes](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf):

### getInteractionQueries() and getLimitInteractionQueries() Limits Methods Removed

> These methods were added as part of a pilot release for Fast
>   Create/Lookup/Update/Delete elements in Visual Workflow, because
>   Visual Workflow used different limits for queries than Apex. Visual
>   Workflow now has the same query limits as Apex, so these methods are
>   no longer needed and have been removed.

Comment: Thanks, I Googled but got nothing!